# Explorer not listing drives for domain account in W2K8 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We have some Windows Server 2008 R2 systems with an issue that I can't seem to figure out. When I log in with an AD account that belongs in the local Administrators group (and no other local groups), I do not see any of the local drives listed in Windows Explorer. I can type the drive letters in the run box and they will open and I have full access - but I can't figure out why they are hidden in Explorer. Additionally, the start menu does not show options for Shutdown or Reboot.

When I log in with a local administrator account, everything is behaving normal. It would appear that there is something in AD that is causing this, but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is caused by Group Policy. Running the "Resultant Set of Policy" tool, pointing to a station with the fault and using a user with the issue, should get you at a point where you know which policy is causing it.

Then you just need to come up with a sensible way around it, such as a separate security group.

The local administrator won't be getting any policies applied as it's not on the domain. However, anyone you add to "Local Administrators" will still get exactly the same policies as they did before.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like a Group Policy issue. I configure these very GPO settings for the TS servers in my TS farm.